# Как при выделение текста запретить событие скролла?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня на странице есть текстовый блок, я выделяю текст и когда доходит курсор до нижней части экрана страничка начинает проскраливать вниз.
Как запретить скролл не запрещая выделение?

Answer (score 5):

```js
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', ()=>{
  const d = getSelection();
  if (d.toString().length > 0){
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
    document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
})
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, corporis!
</div>
```

Дополнил вопрос с учетом комментария, однако это не будет работать если обработчик события повесить на window, document или body;

```js
const app = document.getElementById('app');
app.addEventListener('wheel', (e)=>{
  const d = getSelection();
  if (d.toString().length > 0){
    e.preventDefault();
  } 
})
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde cupiditate et magni ullam aspernatur debitis minima recusandae vero! Libero, eaque reprehenderit fugiat non at aut totam ad iure ab eligendi quis placeat numquam asperiores! Doloribus accusamus ex architecto ad commodi cumque totam maiores, sed dolores distinctio reprehenderit ducimus numquam accusantium obcaecati? Sequi ipsum iure nam dolorem eius repellendus doloremque omnis distinctio rerum soluta laboriosam ratione provident, magni assumenda fugit similique, consectetur perspiciatis aspernatur quis! Cum atque quibusdam qui exercitationem molestiae in debitis. Dolorum saepe molestiae perferendis iusto exercitationem esse fugit recusandae earum! Corporis laboriosam obcaecati natus quia. Cumque nobis perferendis quos libero velit enim voluptates, eos at error adipisci, omnis nisi reprehenderit ex inventore minus quo corrupti odio. Asperiores quaerat est eum quisquam odio minima temporibus commodi cupiditate debitis neque facere voluptas repellat laborum illo molestiae incidunt ipsam saepe repellendus similique ipsa, magni sit maiores laudantium? Rem unde minima consequuntur ut fugit aperiam inventore architecto, obcaecati nisi consectetur laborum vero dolor exercitationem vel dolore. Illo non optio nesciunt laborum, iusto velit quis voluptatem blanditiis quas repellendus placeat aliquid laudantium officia suscipit. Nisi a quisquam soluta cupiditate ipsam non quibusdam officia fugit! Reiciendis incidunt facilis accusamus nihil repellat velit temporibus maxime!
</div>
```

Comment: при скрытии скролла и обратном отображении будут прыжки вправо/влево

Comment: Чтоб второй вариант, повешенный на `window`, `document` или `body` работал, необходимо третьим аргументом для `addEventListener` передать объект такого вида: `{ passive: false }`

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял, автору нужно запретить скролл при выделении, а не только колесом, как вариант - такое решение, при скролле колесом возможны "подёргивания", но зато "запрещается" прокрутка и при выделении, и колесом, и стрелками, и перетаскиванием скроллбара

```js
let currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
let selectionLength = getSelection().toString().length;

// при выделениии записываем текущую прокрутку и длину выделения
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
  currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  selectionLength = getSelection().toString().length;
});

//при попытке прокрутки, если есть выделение, то возвращаем её обратно
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (selectionLength > 0){
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = currentScroll;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Unde cupiditate et magni ullam aspernatur debitis minima recusandae vero! Libero, eaque reprehenderit fugiat non at aut totam ad iure ab eligendi quis placeat numquam asperiores! Doloribus accusamus ex architecto ad commodi cumque totam maiores, sed dolores distinctio reprehenderit ducimus numquam accusantium obcaecati? Sequi ipsum iure nam dolorem eius repellendus doloremque omnis distinctio rerum soluta laboriosam ratione provident, magni assumenda fugit similique, consectetur perspiciatis aspernatur quis! Cum atque quibusdam qui exercitationem molestiae in debitis. Dolorum saepe molestiae perferendis iusto exercitationem esse fugit recusandae earum! Corporis laboriosam obcaecati natus quia. Cumque nobis perferendis quos libero velit enim voluptates, eos at error adipisci, omnis nisi reprehenderit ex inventore minus quo corrupti odio. Asperiores quaerat est eum quisquam odio minima temporibus commodi cupiditate debitis neque facere voluptas repellat laborum illo molestiae incidunt ipsam saepe repellendus similique ipsa, magni sit maiores laudantium? Rem unde minima consequuntur ut fugit aperiam inventore architecto, obcaecati nisi consectetur laborum vero dolor exercitationem vel dolore. Illo non optio nesciunt laborum, iusto velit quis voluptatem blanditiis quas repellendus placeat aliquid laudantium officia suscipit. Nisi a quisquam soluta cupiditate ipsam non quibusdam officia fugit! Reiciendis incidunt facilis accusamus nihil repellat velit temporibus maxime! laborum illo molestiae incidunt ipsam saepe repellendus similique ipsa, magni sit maiores laudantium? Rem unde minima consequuntur ut fugit aperiam inventore architecto, obcaecati nisi consectetur laborum vero dolor exercitationem vel dolore. Illo non optio nesciunt laborum, iusto velit quis voluptatem blanditiis quas repellendus placeat aliquid laudantium officia suscipit. Nisi a quisquam soluta cupiditate ipsam non quibusdam officia fugit! Reiciendis incidunt facilis accusamus nihil repellat velit temporibus maxime!
Reiciendis incidunt facilis accusamus nihil repellat velit temporibus maxime! laborum illo molestiae incidunt ipsam saepe repellendus similique ipsa, magni sit maiores laudantium? Rem unde minima consequuntur ut fugit aperiam inventore architecto, obcaecati nisi consectetur laborum vero dolor exercitationem vel dolore. Illo non optio nesciunt laborum, iusto velit quis voluptatem blanditiis quas repellendus placeat aliquid laudantium officia suscipit. Nisi a quisquam soluta cupiditate ipsam non quibusdam officia fugit! Reiciendis incidunt facilis accusamus nihil repellat velit temporibus maxime!
</div>
```